# React Native Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) - Returning HTML

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting the following error "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)" and it's returning HTML I'm not sure whats causing it or what it means here is the full error:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en-us\" prefix=\"og: http://ogp.me/ns#\">
  <head>
    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">
    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">


<meta name=\"web-experience-app/config/environment\" content=\"%7B%22appVersion%22%3A1%2C%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22web-experience-app%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22production%22%2C%22rootURL%22%3A%22%2F%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22history-hash-router-scroll%22%2C%22historySupportMiddleware%22%3Atrue%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyMeta%22%3Atrue%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%5B%22\'none\'%22%5D%2C%22img-src%22%3A%5B%22\'self\'%22%2C%22*.mzstatic.com%22%2C%22*.apple.com%22%2C%22data%3A%22%5D%2C%22style-src%22%3A%5B%22\'self\'%22%2C%22\'unsafe-inline\'%22%2C%22*.apple.com%22%5D%2C%22font-src%22%3A%5B%22\'self\'%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2F*.apple.com%22%2C%22https%3A%2F%2F*.apple.com%22%5D%2C%22media-src%22%3A%5B%22\'self\'%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2F*.apple.com%22%2C%22*.apple.com%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2F*.akamaihd.net%22%2C%22*.akamaihd.net%22%5D%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%5B%22\'self\'%22%2C%22*.apple.com%22%5D%2C%22script-src%22%3A%5B%22\'self\'%22%2C%22*.apple.com%22%5D%2C%22frame-src%22%3A%5B%22\'self\'%22%2C%22*.apple.com%22%2C%22itmss%3A%22%2C%22itms-appss%3A%22%2C%22itms-bookss%3A%22%2C%22itms-itunesus%3A%22%2C%22itms-messagess%3A%22%2C%22itms-podcasts%3A%22%2C%22itms-watchs%3A%22%2C%22macappstores%3A%22%2C%22musics%3A%22%2C%22apple-musics%3A%22%5D%7D%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22EXTEND_PROTOTYPES%22%3A%7B%22Date%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22web-experience-app%22%2C%22version%22%3A%22v1802.20.0%2B593e10e1%22%7D%2C%22defaultLocale%22%3A%22en-gb%22%2C%22moment%22%3A%7B%22includeLocales%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22browserify%22%3A%7B%22transform%22%3A%5B%5B%22babelify%22%2C%7B%22presets%22%3A%5B%22es2015%22%5D%2C%22global%22%3Atrue%2C%22only%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%5D%7D%2C%22API%22%3A%7B%22MZStore%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%22%2C%22StorePlatform%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fuclient-api.itunes.apple.com%2FWebObjects%2FMZStorePlatform.woa%2Fwa%22%2C%22globalElements%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fweb-experience.itunes.apple.com%2Fglobal-elements%22%7D%2C%22ember-a11y-testing%22%3A%7B%22componentOptions%22%3A%7B%22turnAuditOff%22%3Atrue%2C%22axeOptions%22%3A%7B%22rules%22%3A%7B%22color-contrast%22%3A%7B%22enabled%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22assetHost%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fweb-experience.itunes.apple.com%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyHeader%22%3A%22Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only%22%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Afalse%7D\" />
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Security-Policy\" content=\"default-src \'none\'; img-src \'self\' *.mzstatic.com *.apple.com data:; style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\' *.apple.com; font-src \'self\' http://*.apple.com https://*.apple.com; media-src \'self\' http://*.apple.com *.apple.com http://*.akamaihd.net *.akamaihd.net; connect-src \'self\' *.apple.com; script-src \'self\' *.apple.com; frame-src \'self\' *.apple.com itmss: itms-appss: itms-bookss: itms-itunesus: itms-messagess: itms-podcasts: itms-watchs: macappstores: musics: apple-musics:; \">
<!-- EMBER_CLI_FASTBOOT_TITLE --><meta name=\"ember-cli-head-start\"><title>Construction Cloud on the App Store</title>
<link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/construction-cloud/id1093802452?mt=8\">
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"//www.apple.com/wss/fonts?families=SF+Pro,v1|SF+Pro+Icons,v1\">
<link rel=\"manifest\" href=\"https://apps.mzstatic.com/content/static-config/android/manifest.json\">
  <meta name=\"description\" content=\"Read reviews, compare customer ratings, see screenshots, and learn more about Construction Cloud. Download Construction Cloud and enjoy it on your Apple TV.\" id=\"ember45210644\" class=\"ember-view\">


  </body>
</html>"
```

Answer (score 1):

This was cased the the following package - react-native-version-check

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code and why it was causing problems? I find it hard to believe that the package was the only one involved.

Comment: Here is the issue - https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check/issues/21